# DKIM verification fails when KEY is created using PHP code

Tags: php, dkim

DKIM verification fails when DKIM keys (private, public) are created using PHP code.

```
<?php

//Set these to match your domain and chosen DKIM selector
$domain = 'deepak.co.in';
$selector = 'cst';

//Private key filename for this selector
$privatekeyfile = $selector .'.' .$domain.'.pem';
//Public key filename for this selector
$publickeyfile = $selector . '_dkim_public.pem';

if (file_exists($privatekeyfile)) {
    echo "Using existing keys - if you want to generate new keys, delete old key files first.\n\n";
    $privatekey = file_get_contents($privatekeyfile);
    $publickey = file_get_contents($publickeyfile);
} else {
    //Create a 2048-bit RSA key with an SHA256 digest
    $pk = openssl_pkey_new(
        [
            'digest_alg' => 'rsa',
            'private_key_bits' => 2048,
            'private_key_type' => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
        ]
    );
    //Save private key

    var_dump($pk);
    //exit;
    openssl_pkey_export_to_file($pk, $privatekeyfile);
    //Save public key
    $pubKey = openssl_pkey_get_details($pk);
    $publickey = $pubKey['key'];
    file_put_contents($publickeyfile, $publickey);

    $privatekey = file_get_contents($privatekeyfile);
}
echo "<pre>"."Private key (keep this private!):\n\n" . $privatekey;
echo "\n\nPublic key:\n\n" . $publickey;

//Prepare public key for DNS, e.g.
//phpmailer._domainkey.example.com IN TXT "v=DKIM1; h=sha256; t=s; p=" "MIIBIjANBg...oXlwIDAQAB"...
$dnskey = "$selector._domainkey.$domain IN TXT";
//$dnsvalue = '"v=DKIM1; h=sha256; t=s; p=';
$dnsvalue = 'v=DKIM1; h=sha256; p=';
//Some DNS servers don't like ;(semi colon) chars unless backslash-escaped
//$dnsvalue2 = '"v=DKIM1\; h=sha256\; t=s\; p=';
$dnsvalue2 = 'v=DKIM1\; h=sha256\; p=';

//Strip and split the key into smaller parts and format for DNS
//Many DNS systems don't like long TXT entries
//but are OK if it's split into 255-char chunks
//Remove PEM wrapper
$publickey = preg_replace('/^-+.*?-+$/m', '', $publickey);
//Strip line breaks
$publickey = str_replace(["\r", "\n"], '', $publickey);
//Split into chunks
$keyparts = str_split($publickey, 253); //Becomes 255 when quotes are included
//Quote each chunk
foreach ($keyparts as $keypart) {
    //$dnsvalue .= '"' . trim($keypart) . '" ';
    //$dnsvalue2 .= '"' . trim($keypart) . '" ';

    $dnsvalue .=trim($keypart);
    $dnsvalue2 .= trim($keypart);
}
echo "\n\nDNS key:\n\n" . trim($dnskey);
echo "\n\nDNS value:\n\n" . trim($dnsvalue);

$first_part_str = substr($dnsvalue, 0,253);

$brk_created_dkim_using_first_part_str = explode($first_part_str, $dnsvalue);
echo "\n\n DKIM TO BE USE \n\n";
echo $to_use_dkim_2048_bit = '"' .$first_part_str. '""'.$brk_created_dkim_using_first_part_str[1].'"';

//echo "\n\nDNS value (with escaping):\n\n" . trim($dnsvalue2);
?>
```

The above code is referred from `https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/DKIM_gen_keys.phps`
Only few things we have changed as per need.

When DKIM keys are created from third party website-:

```
https://www.sparkpost.com/resources/tools/dkim-wizard/
```

DKIM get passed in mail box, but when created using above script at mail box in shows `dkim=perm_fail`. Where are things going wrong?

[image]

Comment: _"Only few things we have changed"_ I'd start here. Obvious first test is, do keys created from the unmodified code work?

Comment: Yes Alex we had tested the code without modification at that point also DKIM key verification failed. Things we changed is the name of the file, selector and at the end breaking the key because on aws route53 keys with big size can be added in parts. Same mechanism of adding keys we followed when created DKIM from sparkpost. Breaking the key into 2 parts enclosing them with double quotes.